# $match aggregation is giving me None (in terms of Python) If ISO date is not present in query it will give null output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

$match  aggregation is giving me None (in terms of Python) even though I have verified it multiple time entries are present in DB .
In Python pymongo is not recognizing the ISO while I write inside the cursor = {}
making ISO as string and concatenating it with the time also doesn't work it gives the empty list .
same case with all operator gte or lte .

db.cityhistory.find({"updateTime": ISODate("2018-04-20T13:27:39.021+0000"), "countries.city": {"$exists": true}}, {"countries.city": 1})

Comment: db.cityhistory.aggregate([
        
        { "$project": {"countries.city": 1} },
        { "$match": {"updateTime": {"eq":("2018-04-20T19:57:30.000+0000")} } },
        { "$unwind": "$countries.city" },
        { "$group": { "_id": "result", "count": {"$sum": 1} } }
        ])

Comment: *" pymongo is not recognizing the ISO"* That's because when you actually **read** the marked duplicate instead of complaining, then you will see that you use the `datetime` module for dates when working with python.